# BItTorrent PIECE size

Tags: bittorrent

I am bit confused about the PIECE size specification in BitTorrent protocol.
To be specific, the torrent metainfo file, I am experimenting with, says that each piece should be 65536 bytes (except the last one which is (total_file_size - remaining bytes)). But the length of PIECE messages arriving is 16384 bytes, with the same number of pieces as specified by metainfo file.
It happens with every torrent - PIECE size specified by metainfo file is different from the size of PIECE messages arriving.
Am I missing something in the protocol ?

Answer (score 5):

The PIECE message is used to transfer *a part of* a piece, which is commonly called a block. Most implementations seem to use a block size of 16K, which explains the behaviour you  observed. The block size is set in each REQEUEST message.

For more information on this part of the BitTorrent protocol, I highly recommend [this wiki page](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#request:_.3Clen.3D0013.3E.3Cid.3D6.3E.3Cindex.3E.3Cbegin.3E.3Clength.3E).